# Run cron jobs inside of Docker container

Tags: python, docker, cron

I'm trying to run my python program every minute in a Docker container. To do this I want to build image with Python and cron and then with cron expression run `main.py`.

Can you please look at my Dockerfile and tell me why nothing is executing? Even the second cron expr (`echo "OK"`) is not writing to a file (I've added it as a debug job).

All log files are empty, just like the cron would not work at all...

BTW. if I would run `/script.sh` manually (from docker container) I receive no errors and a new line is added to `/app/ROOT.log`.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
RUN apt-get -y install procps

RUN touch /script.sh
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" >> /script.sh \
    && echo "" >> /script.sh \
    && echo "cd /app" >> /script.sh \
    && echo "python main.py" >> /script.sh
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /script.sh >/app/cron.log 2>&1") | crontab
RUN (crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * echo \"OK\" >>/app/cron.log 2>&1") | crontab
RUN chown app:app /script.sh && chown -R app:app /var/spool/cron/crontabs
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

WORKDIR /app

# copy requirements.txt file from local (source) to file structure of container (destination) 
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

# Install the requirements specified in file using RUN
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# copy all items in current local directory (source) to current container directory (destination)
COPY main.py main.py

CMD /etc/init.d/cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

`main.py`:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from datetime import datetime
    # save current date time to file
    with open('/app/ROOT.log', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(datetime.now()) + '\n')
```

```bash
root@86bbd19a7cb1:/app# ps aux | grep cron
root         1  0.0  0.0   2384   756 ?        Ss   12:49   0:00 /bin/sh -c /etc/init.d/cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
root        11  0.0  0.0   7260  2056 ?        Ss   12:49   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root        12  0.0  0.0   4076   744 ?        S    12:49   0:00 tail -f /var/log/cron.log
root        38  0.0  0.0   4832   876 pts/0    S+   12:54   0:00 grep cron
```

```bash
root@86bbd19a7cb1:/app# ls /var/log/
alternatives.log  apt  btmp  cron.log  dpkg.log  exim4  faillog  lastlog  wtmp
root@86bbd19a7cb1:/app# cat /var/log/cron.log
root@86bbd19a7cb1:/app# cat /var/log/lastlog
root@86bbd19a7cb1:/app# cat /var/log/faillog
```

Comment: What do you see in the output from `tail -f`?

Comment: Nothing, it's just hangs

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add "-" after crontab for it to process input.

`RUN (crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /script.sh >/app/cron.log 2>&1") | crontab`

would be:
`RUN (crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /script.sh >/app/cron.log 2>&1") | crontab -`

Reference: [How to create a cron job using Bash automatically without the interactive editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878600/how-to-create-a-cron-job-using-bash-automatically-without-the-interactive-editor)

Most other answers / guides also suggest using `sort -u` to remove possible duplicate entries like so:

`RUN (crontab -l ; echo "*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /script.sh >/app/cron.log 2>&1") | sort -u | crontab -`

Comment: In Dockerfile I'm creating cron.log `RUN touch /var/log/cron.log`. File `/app/cron.log` does not exists (cause cron did not ran)

Comment: To preserve your own sanity as well as ours, maybe don't have two files with the same name in different directories and with different purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure about this. If I run `crontab -l` I have all, 2 entries

Comment: It might just be good practice then.  Read your post again and saw that running manually does output the expected line. Maybe touch all your files and chmod them 777 just to elliminate the file access from the equasion?

Comment: Setting permissions to 777 still does not work :/

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73899272/22876455